# Queries regarding basics of PCA

Tags: matlab, statistics, computer-vision, pca, feature-selection

I want to use PCA for the feature selection with CNN features. From the theory of PCA, the data should correlated. After extracting the features from CNN the features are organized is this way `[f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6]` and the corresponding labels are `[L1 L1 L2 L2 L3 L3]`. How can I check my data is correlated? And if the data is not correlated then how can I make one?

Comment: High-dimensional data is always* correlated. If you're talking about CNNs, the "C" part is for convolution, which further enforces some form of correlation. But of course that depends on where within the CNN you are taking the features. *Unless specifically generated to not be correlated of course.

Comment: I don't really understand *From the theory of PCA, the data should correlated* or *And if the data is not correlated then how can I make one?*. PCA is a technique for reducing data with *possibly* correlated features to a smaller set of *uncorrelated* features. What problem do you think you currently have with using PCA? Also as it stands this is a statistics question not a programming one.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have 5 layer network and I am taking feature layer 3 , 4 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that for meaningful PCA there should be correlation between columns of input to PCA. However you only have one vector of features as PCA input, so correlation and PCA cannot be applied. One thing you can do is compute correlation between the waits of each feature [f1..f6] with the other. Similarly you can then apply PCA to the matrix of weights. But my feeling is that you are trying to apply feature reduction method (PCA) in en environment that has too few features in the first place. You might reduce the features from 6 to 3 (to classify [L1..L3]), but adding a fully connected layer with 3 nodes may do the same in a more standard approach.
Here is an example using vgg16.

```
net=vgg16;
[~,score]=pca(net.Layers(39).Weights);
figure;
plot(score(:,1))
```

PCA scores for the first component are high for label 1 to 398 (natural classes), and low for 399 to 1000 (artificial classes). This means that at least some PCA components are useful for grouping nodes together. Checking correlations between weights reveal that indeed there are, with max correlation  at about 0.7. I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Actually, I am taking features from different layers such later 5, 7 and 9. and combining the features of these layers to one. if the features of layer 5 is 4000, layer 7 is 500 and layer 9 is 50. Then the total features I have 4550 features. Now I want to reduce these 4550 features to for example 400. That's why I am applying PCA.

Comment: If you can make a meaningful two dimentional matrix , you can then test correlations and apply PCA